# Flipper-DoubleConversion requires CocoaPods version >= 1.9 which is not satisfied by your current version 1.8.4

Tags: ios, reactjs, xcode, react-native, cocoapods

When I run pod install inside iOS directory

I get the following error:

```
[!] `Flipper-DoubleConversion` requires CocoaPods version `>= 1.9`,
 which is not satisfied by your current version, `1.8.4`.
```

I did install pod install but did not fix the issue, but it's working on Android OS.


Package.json

```
"@fawazahmed/react-native-read-more": "^2.2.2",
"@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "^1.15.13",
"@react-native-community/checkbox": "^0.5.9",
"@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.11",
"faker": "^5.5.3",
"iamport-react-native": "^2.0.0-rc.1",
"moment": "^2.29.1",
"react": "17.0.2",
"react-native": "^0.66.3",
"react-native-animatable": "^1.3.3",
"react-native-datepicker": "^1.7.2",
"react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.10.3",
"react-native-image-crop-picker": "^0.37.2",
"react-native-linear-gradient": "^2.5.6",
"react-native-network-info": "^5.2.1",
"react-native-onesignal": "^4.3.3",
"react-native-pagination": "^1.5.5",
"react-native-popup-menu": "^0.15.12",
"react-native-raw-bottom-sheet": "^2.2.0",
"react-native-read-more-text": "^1.1.2",
"react-native-safe-area-context": "^3.3.2",
"react-native-show-more-button": "^1.0.2",
"react-native-swiper": "^1.6.0",
"react-native-vector-icons": "^9.0.0",
"react-native-webview": "^11.15.0",
"react-navigation": "^4.4.4",
"react-navigation-stack": "^2.10.4",
"toggle-switch-react-native": "^3.3.0"
```

Comment: Try updating your Cocoapods version.

Comment: @AkshayShenoy I did, but not worked.

Comment: @SamimHakimi did you solve this problem?